# About Python Pandas, drop the row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

all.

I created Python code that imports excel file and if it matches conditions, drop the raw using "while" and "if" states. After finishing a comparison, export an excel file as a result.
There is no error coded but dropping raw is not working because when I open a result excel file, it is exactly same as imported excel file. I think "data.drop(data.index[pointer+a])" is not working.
Could you help me out?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('20190924_1147-50_result.xlsx', index_col = 0)
print('\nExcel file reading complete')                                                    
a = 1                                                                                     
pointer = 0                                                                               
del_indicator = 0

data = data.drop_duplicates(['Src IP', 'Dst IP', 'Dst Port'], keep='first')              
print('SrcIP, DstIP, Dst Port are Deduplicated\n')                                        

while True:
    if pointer == 2906 :       
        print(pointer, data.iloc[pointer, 3])        
        break
    elif pointer+a == 2906 :   
        pointer +=1
        a = 1
    elif data.iloc[pointer, 2] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 3] and data.iloc[pointer, 3] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 2] and data.iloc[pointer, 6] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 5]:
        print('\n-----', data.iloc[pointer, 0], data.iloc[pointer, 2], data.iloc[pointer, 3])      
        print('-----', data.iloc[pointer+a, 0], data.iloc[pointer+a, 2], data.iloc[pointer+a, 3])   

        data.drop(data.index[pointer+a])

        a+=1            
    else:             
        a+=1           

print('Deleting session traffic Finished')

data.to_excel('20190924_1147-50_result_test.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Using data') 
print('Finished creating result excel file')
```

Comment: You will have to use **inplace=True** parameter with data.drop to persist the changes to original dataframe.

Comment: When I change to "data.drop(data.index[pointer+a], inplace=True)", error messages came up like below                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OneDrive - Continental AG\Work\01_Network\13_Firewall\20190401_WannaCry_FW\Port      ~~~ and finally IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Maybe the index that you are trying to drop does not exist. You will have to check further on this. Do you want to drop rows specific to particular index ?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I'm trying to drop which is not exist. I want to drop raws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do the following small changes

```
data.drop(data.index[pointer+a], inplace=True)  # add inplace
# or another solution data = data.drop(data.index[pointer+a])
```

It seems to me that you did not save changes to data.

Comment: When I change to "data.drop(data.index[pointer+a], inplace=True)", error messages came up like                                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OneDrive - Continental AG\Work\01_Network\13_Firewall\20190401_WannaCry_FW\Port survey\packet_list_test_iloc_index.py", line 23, in <module>
    elif data.iloc[pointer, 2] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 3] and data.iloc[pointer, 3] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 2] and data.iloc[pointer, 6] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 5]:    # If condition is meeted, drop the raw

Comment: File "C:\Users\uids5345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\uids5345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2092, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup) File "C:\Users\uids5345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 235, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key(k, i)

Comment: File "C:\Users\uids5345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2014, in _validate_key
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\uids5345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2088, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: I should change the algorithm. I think the total number of raw is changed whenever raw is deleted so that blank index comes up..

Comment: @Jun after you have changed df, it does not answer the requiremnets of data.iloc[pointer, 2] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 3] and data.iloc[pointer, 3] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 2] and data.iloc[pointer, 6] == data.iloc[pointer+a, 5] line, presumably it has appropriate first or second index in iloc, because it became smaller. After data.drop(data.index[pointer+a], inplace=True) add print(data) to see how df looks like after you have changed it, it will suggest you why it is out of index now.

Comment: Yeah.. you are right. I omit detail data, just show how many rows and columns    ----- 1 10.221.172.31 10.219.14.119
----- 347 10.219.14.119 10.221.172.31                                                        
[2906 rows x 9 columns]                                                                                      ----- 2 10.219.11.115 10.219.18.251
----- 27 10.219.18.251 10.219.11.115                                                           
 [2905 rows x 9 columns]

Comment: Now I should change the question :) How can I handle the index pointer after drop rows? Whenever it deletes raw, I have to change "pointer" value

Comment: @Jun well I do not know how you use pointer param, but you need to analyze changes in frame, then inside this elif you change pointer value accordingly to df

Comment: Thank you!! It was sososo helpful. Have a nice day